# counting word instances in a string

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how this piece of python code below works. It counts the number of times 'bob' is found in 's'  Specifically, i don't understand the role of 'i'. Any help would be much appreciated! I searched around and couldn't figure out the answer.

Additionally, this is my first post here, so if i am not following protocol/norms in any way, please feel free to let me know!

```
s = 'aeioubobaeioubob'
numBobs = 0
for i in range(1, len(s)-1):
    if s[i-1:i+2] == 'bob':
        numBobs += 1
print 'Number of times bob occurs is:', numBobs
```

Comment: Easier way:  `s.count('bob')`

Comment: You are just iterating the whole length of string. Try to use print statements.

Comment: with i, you are looping through all characters of s and check if three consecutive characters are equals to "bob"

Comment: How many times does `bob` exist in the word `bobob`?  One or two?

Comment: If you don't know what `i`  is  I suggest you read a very basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"i" is a variable used to keep track of what iteration you are on for the loop. "i" starts at 1 and each iteration is incremented by 1.

The "s[i:i+3]" means "the values in s from the character at 'i' to the character at 'i+3'".

Comment: "i" starts at 0: well, it probably *should*, but it doesn't in the code the OP posted.

Comment: You are very welcome! :D Happy to help, sometimes little simple things at the beginning are hard and Stack Overflow can be harsh on newbies :D Please make sure to accept the answer as correct :D